# Ionic 4: ion-select doesn’t work well on IOS

Tags: ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, ionic4

When on IOS, ion-select doesn’t trigger choices when tapping on it. It does so when tapping on its boundaries / borders.

An example of faulty code :

```
    <ion-list>
    <ion-item no-padding>
      <ion-label position="floating">{{'GENDER' | translate}}</ion-label>
      <ion-select formControlName="gender">
        <ion-select-option value="male">{{"MALE" | translate}}</ion-select-option>
        <ion-select-option value="female">{{"FEMALE" | translate}}</ion-select-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The faulty part is the `position="floating"` on the `label` element. Removing it, or putting something else like `stacked` fixes the issue.

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item no-padding>
    <ion-label>{{'GENDER'}}</ion-label>
    <ion-select formControlName="gender">
      <ion-select-option value="male">{{"MALE" }}</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="female">{{"FEMALE"}}</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `tappable` attribute to `<ion-item>`:

```
<ion-list>
 <ion-item tappable no-padding>
    <ion-label position="floating">{{'GENDER' | translate}}</ion-label>
    <ion-select formControlName="gender">
    <ion-select-option value="male">{{"MALE" | translate}}</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="female">{{"FEMALE" | translate}}</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
 </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: Nope, it doesn't help, sadly

Comment: @JeremyBelolo please check this link https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/5838#issuecomment-196592935 , as suggested try to wrap it with a `div` and add `tappable`. Please also inform me.

Comment: Okay, no that's not it at all, thanks though :) This one is about the delay, where I'm reporting the component to be broken - not working when tapping on it, only on its edge